# Rendering an input field for picklist value

Tags: visualforce, picklist

I have a picklist field with value - Test's (ABC) and want to render an input field if picklist value is as above

[image]

The input field is not rendering. Is there any other way to check for round brackets in picklist values. have tried \ also. Didnt worked out.

Comment: You can write the logic for that rendered in your controller only and just return true or false and render based on that ?Not sure why you want to add logic in view layer

Comment: Can you please give me a sample code for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JSENCODE()` function:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!acc.name}" 
                 rendered="{!JSENCODE(acc.picklist__c) = 'Test\'s (ABC)'}"/>
```

Here more onfo about functions: [JSENCONDE](http://na9.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_functions_i_z.htm#JSENCODE)

Comment: great it worked wonders

Comment: Sure. Have done it.. :)